# Inflating a transparent layout that overlaps actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to inflate a layout that overlaps include action bar but I failed to do so after searching around for hours.

My current approach is hide action bar before inflating the layout but i don't really like it.

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.frame_container, new WatchMyBackFragment()).commit();
```

**Sorry i could not attach image as my reputation is below 10.**

Comment: Upload image somewhere and put a link in question

Comment: @Apurva thanks for your advice. Totally forgot that as i am exhausted. :(

Comment: http://imgur.com/p7a2NF8 this is the effect i wanted to achieve

Comment: In the image I see that the layout is partially transparent and it has NO actionbar, the actionbar seems is of layout behind it.